# OP highlighting overlaps line above in comments

Tags: bug, design

Hopefully this image is clear:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The `q` and `y` of `Inquiry` are cut off by the highlighting of the OP's name. This seems to be unique to this site - something to do with the font and the size of the OP background?

The font here is Open Sans, 13px and line spacing of 17px in the comments.

Here is a photo of a comment on Ask Ubuntu:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The font there is Ubuntu 13px, with line spacing of 17px.

Comment: Sample comment showing problem: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48029/dry-cleaners-lost-160-pants-what-should-i-do#comment73048_48029